# Generate signed APK error com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

when generate signed apk, has this error, but build project is ok

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://raw.github.com/71241NW123CK/maven-repo/master'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.baclock"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2018.02.09"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'party.treesquaredcode.android:flip-animation:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `multiDexEnabled true` in default config and then try.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.baclock"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2018.02.09"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/ICUCompatIcs.class

Comment: thanks, need to set multiDexEnabled = true and minSdkVersion > 20

Comment: so you don't want to increase the minimum sdk version or is it working for you now?.

Comment: yes, now is ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add **multiDexEnabled = true** inside defaultConfig block.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.baclock"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2018.02.09"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/ICUCompatIcs.class

Comment: thanks, need to set multiDexEnabled = true and minSdkVersion > 20